# Create links to cloud private notebook directly opening in Wolfram Player on iOS

Tags: wolfram-cloud, hyperlink

I've learned to save notebooks on Wolfram Cloud with what looks like a permanent link using `CloudDeploy[SelectedNotebook[], "user:myusername/path/to/file"]` the output of this operation is "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/myusername/myusername/path/to/file".
What I'd like to now do with this is to translate this link to something that triggers Wolfram Player on mobile devices.

By inspecting the iOS app bundle I've learned that it associates 4 URL schemes:
`wolfram+cloudobject`,
`wolframdesktop+cloudobject`,
`wolfram+helpreference` and `wolframplayer`, that trigger the app to open. However, I've been unable to get any more than that (app opens, but does not open the notebook).

I've tried various combinations, like:
`wolframplayer:///user:myusername/path/to/file`
`wolframplayer:///obj/myusername/path/to/file`, etc. but none of those seem to work.

Also, I'm logged in to my account in Wolfram Player.

[Edit]: I've tried to extract the link from the web version that invokes Wolfram Desktop and the link was in format
`wolfram+cloudobject:www.wolframcloud.com/env/myusername/path/to/file`
but this and neither
`wolframplayer:www.wolframcloud.com/env/myusername/path/to/file`
did not work on mobile.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I’m also looking for a solution.